# Explain this situation of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm learning pointers and I get lost in this code:

```
    template<typename T>
    inline T export(const char *dll, const char *name)
    {
        return (T) ((void *(*)(const char *, const char *))GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(dll), name));
    }
```

To be more exact, I don't understand the part where it does some weird conversion of void pointer(s).
Even more exact problem: What does `*(*)` do and when can you use it?

Comment: It casts the `void*` (pointer to void) returned from `GetProcAddress` to a pointer to function, which returns `void*`, and takes 2 parameters of type `const char *`.

Comment: http://cdecl.org/ can help for at least part of this: feed the string `void *(*test)(const char *, const char *)` to it to describe the type that participates in the casting

Answer (score 2):

`(void *(*)(const char *, const char *)` means you are casting the following function to a function pointer `(*)` that returns a void pointer `void *` and takes two constant char pointers `(const char *, const char *)` as parameters

Such a function pointer by itself might be declared as

```
(void *(*foo)(const char *, const char *);
```

Answer (score 1):

`void *(*)(const char *, const char *)` is a function pointer which returns `void*` and takes as arguments 2 `const char *`.

```
void *   (*)       (const char *, const char *)
^^^^^^    ^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      
return  pointer     signature
value
```

So basically, this casts the returned value of `GetProcAddress` to `void *(*)(const char *, const char *)` and then casts it to `T`

Comment: But you can't always use `*(*)` can you?

Comment: @dadasdasdas `*(*)` is not one thing. The first asterisk is part of the type `void*`.

Comment: Oh god. I totally misread it. I thought it's just `*(*)` the whole time... Thanks for noticing it out, I would be totally lost otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

The `(*)` says "this is a function pointer".
The thing to the right, `(const char *, const char *)`, is the parameter types.
The thing to the left, `void *`, is the return type.

So it casts the result from `GetProcAddress` to the function pointer type `void *(*)(const char *, const char *)`.

The cast is completely pointless as the result is immediately cast to the type `T` provided by the caller.

The function also has one of the more confusing names ever invented, as it does the opposite of exporting.

Comment: Thanks for describing it in such details, I have really hard time with pointers, I can do stuff with single pointer but It is hard for me to keep it up with more than one pointer, pointers really confuse me. Thanks really!

Answer (score 1):

```
(T) ((void *(*)(const char *, const char *))GetProcAddress(...)
```

The value returned by `GetProcAddress()` is converted twice: once to a pointer to a function that receives two arguments of type `const char *` and returns a `void *` then the result is converted to type `T`

The `C`/`C++` variable and type declarations are decoded from inside out. Start with the variable or type name, check on the right for `()` (function) or `[]` (array) then on the left for the type of the values returned by the function or contained in the array but without crossing the parentheses. Remove the inner set of parentheses and repeat.

For example:

```
void *(*p)(const char *, const char *)
```

`p` is (nothing on the right, not crossing the parentheses) a pointer (`*` on the left) to (escape one level of parentheses) a function having two arguments of type `const char *` (`(...)` on the right) that returns `void *` (on the left).

To recap, `p` is a pointer to a function that receives two `const char *` arguments and returns `void *`.

`p` above is a variable. If the entire declaration is prefixed with `typedef`, `p` becomes the definition of a new type.

Without `p` (and without `typedef`) it is an anonymous type that is used in the question for type casting: by placing it inside parentheses, the value returned by `GetProcAddress()` is converted to the type described above. The `(T)` in front of it forces another conversion to type `T`.

---

In the posted expression, the complex type described above is enclosed in two pairs of parentheses. Only one pair is needed. The other one can be safely removed.